# Share enum between client and WCF service?

Tags: c#, wcf, enums

I am having problems sharing my public enum class from my WCF service down to my client program.
(I want to be able to access every enum attributes from my client program). (I have added my service as i Service Reference).
(For testing I only have two EnumMemer - I know..)

I have this in my Service.svc.cs file:

```
namespace ITHelperService
{
[DataContract]
public class Service : IService
{
    [DataMember]
    public CommandsEnums comands;

    [DataContract(Name="CommandsEnums")]
    public enum CommandsEnums
    {
        [EnumMember]
        Get_IPConfig,
        [EnumMember]
        Get_IPConfig_all,
        Get_BIOSVersion,
        Get_JavaVersion,
        Get_RecentInstalledPrograms,
        Get_RecentEvents,
        Get_WEIScore,
        Do_Ping,
        Do_NSLookup
    }
}
}
```

And this is my IService.cs file:

```
namespace ITHelperService
{
[ServiceContract]
[ServiceKnownType(typeof(ITHelperService.Service.CommandsEnums))]
public interface IService
{


}
}
```

I have searched the Internet about this problem and it seems that the above should do the trick.
But I can't access them in my client program. It doesn't show up in the intellisense.

Any input please?

Comment: can u relocate datacontract entity to new project and add references from these?

Comment: Have you updated the client? Offtopic: Also I would suggest making `comands` a property and properly cased: `public CommandsEnum Comand { get; set; }`. By convention an enum that is not flagged as `[Flags]` should be singularized and plural if it is.

Comment: Could you try and move the enum out of the class and declare it on its own? Be interested to see if that resolves the issue.

Comment: Moved the enum out on its own (of course, my bad ;)) But I still can not access it. Just to be sure, how should I be able to access it on the client? Code example please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are confusing a few things here.

1. The IService does not have any Operations in it. A ServiceContract should have a few OperationContracts, that you implement in your Service class.
2. The Implementation of your IService, the Service class, should NOT be a DataContract! It is your implementation of the IService interface.
3. The Enum CommandsEnums should maybe not be inside the implementation of the Service class, as Simon pointed out.

I would suggest smth like this:
IService.cs file:

```
namespace ITHelperService
{
 [ServiceContract]
 [ServiceKnownType(typeof(ITHelperService.Service.CommandsEnums))]
 public interface IService
 {
  [OperationContract]
  void Test();
 }
}
```

Service.svc.cs file:

```
namespace ITHelperService
{
[DataContract]
public class Service : IService
{
    public void Test()
    {
     // This is the method that you can call from your client
    }

}

 [DataContract(Name="CommandsEnums")]
    public enum CommandsEnums
    {
        [EnumMember]
        Get_IPConfig,
        [EnumMember]
        Get_IPConfig_all,
        Get_BIOSVersion,
        Get_JavaVersion,
        Get_RecentInstalledPrograms,
        Get_RecentEvents,
        Get_WEIScore,
        Do_Ping,
        Do_NSLookup
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you Florian. But I still cannot see the enums on my client. I can see the Test method, like: Svc.Test(); But how should I access the enums from the client?

Comment: I dont really understand what you want to do with the enums, can you explain a bit more what information you want to get from the server?

Answer (score 0):

Your enum shouldn't be included with the server-side code. If you want to share common code, then put it in a common location. That way both the client and server can reference it.

Comment: Could you please explain what "common location" could be? I quite new to this :) Thank you

Comment: You have a project that's a client, right? And you have a project that's a server, right? Create another project (class library), called ITHelperCommon. Then put your enum in there. Then your client and your server would have to reference ITHelperCommon.